# Multicolumn dependent average function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with customers of a travel agency with 4 columns: customerID, country visited, city visited and amount spent in that country/city combination.

A customer might have visited a city multiple times with different amounts spent.

[image]

I want to query the customerID's from those customers that:

1. Have visited at least two cities in distinct countries
2. Have an average spending difference between those cities of at least 5000.

I have aggregated it so that I get the average spent for each city per customer:

```
SELECT customerid, country, city, AVG(amount_spent)
FROM Customers
GROUP BY customerid, country, city, amount_spent;
```

I get this:

[image]

How would I only output the customers with the two conditions met, which in this case would only be customerID 7. Customerid 9 should not be output because he does not visit two cities in distinct countries and 8 should not be output because the difference in average spent is less than 5000.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret this as at least two cities in different countries meeting the amount spent condition.  The tricky part is that the cities need to be in different countries -- and someone could visit more than two cities.

To solve this, aggregate (correctly) to get the average amount spent in each city.  Then use a self-join to meet the conditions:

```
WITH cc AS (
      SELECT customerid, country, city, AVG(amount_spent) as avg_amount_spent
      FROM Customers
      GROUP BY customerid, country, city
     )
SELECT DISTINCT cc1.customer_id
FROM cc cc1 JOIN
     cc cc2
     ON cc1.customerid = cc2.customerid AND
        cc1.country <> cc2.country AND
        cc1.avg_amount_spent > cc2.avg_amount_spent + 5000
```